# How to beat JSoup access denied java.net.SocketPermission in tomcat 6?

Tags: tomcat, jsoup

I got  exception `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission www.somepage.net:80 connect,resolve)` when I try

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.somepage.net/").get();
```

in web app in Tomcat 6. However if I do this in `mvn test` outside of tomcat 6 or in another web app in tc server all is going great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the `/conf/catalina.policy` file to grant `java.net.SocketPermission` on the code in question.

See also [Tomcat 6.0 Security Manager HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html).

Comment: thanks, I added 'permission java.net.SocketPermission "*", "connect";' line to /var/lib/tomcat6/conf/policy.d/04webapps.policy and now it's working wonderfully.